# SWIG: variadic template with zero argument

Tags: java, c++11, swig, variadic-templates

From SWIG documentation:

> For now however, the %template directive only accepts one parameter
>   substitution for the variable template parameters.

However, is it possible to make workaround for using variadic template with zero arguments with SWIG like

```
struct S {
  template <typename T, typename... Args>
  std::shared_ptr<T> fn(Args&&... args) const;
};

%template(Si) S::fn<int>; /* <-- Error: Template 'fn' undefined. */
```

Comment: If you include the template arguments in the outermost struct, it should be possible

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround if you lie in the SWIG interface and write:

```
struct S {
  template <typename T, typename... Args>
  std::shared_ptr<T> fn(Args&&... args) const;

  std::shared_ptr<int> fn() const;
};
```

Then wrapper code that calls the 0 argument variadic template function will be generated for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already made almost the same   `%extend S { std::shared_ptr<int> fn_int() const {
    return $self->fn<int>();
  }`

Comment: @triclosan That works well (but slightly differently) as an answer - you could post it as an answer yourself if you wanted

Answer (score 0):

As was advised in comments I'm answering by myself. I used such type of wrappers for generating variadic templates specialization with any number of arguments.

```
%extend S { 
std::shared_ptr<int> fn_int() const { return $self->fn<int>(); }
std::shared_ptr<double> fn_double(int i, int j) const { return $self->fn<double>(i, j); }
}
```